# Why does God promise Zedekiah a peaceful death?

Tags: repentance

Jeremiah 34:4-5 includes a promise for this seemingly unrepentant king to die a peaceful death. Why does God offer him this when king Josiah died by the sword? Was this a conditional promise, and if so, how do we know?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ashlynn. That's a worthwhile question to pursue, but on here (when two specific verses are being asked about) it's good practice to include them, as a quote, saying which translation you are using. You could add that as an Edit to your question. That would really help promote answers.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what God promised king Zedekiah, through Jeremiah the prophet:

> “And thou shalt not escape out of his hand, but shalt surely be taken,
> and delivered into his hand; and thine eyes shall behold the eyes of
> the king of Babylon, and he shall speak with thee mouth to mouth, and
> thou shalt go to Babylon… Thou shalt not die by the sword; but thou
> shall die in peace” Jeremiah 34:3-5 A.V.

***Those verses themselves do not give the reason*** for God saying Zedekiah’s death would not be by the sword. In the sense that ***he would not die while leading his troops in a war, that may be viewed as comparatively peaceful - dying naturally***. The full historic account must be searched for the complete story. As the crisis developed, Zedekiah failed in vital respects, despite God’s prophet warning him and showing him the opportunities he had to prevent Jerusalem being destroyed. It ended up as he had been told – he saw his own sons killed by the king of Babylon, after which Zedekiah had his eyes gouged out, living like that till his death:

> “…when they had taken him, they brought him up to Nebuchadnezzar king
> of Babylon to Riblah in the land of Hamath, where he gave judgment
> upon him. Then the king of Babylon slew the sons of Zedekiah in Riblah
> before his eyes: also the king of Babylon slew all the nobles of
> Judah. Moreover he put out Zedekiah’s eyes, and bound him with chains,
> to carry him to Babylon.” Jeremiah 39:5-7 A.V.

Therefore, Zedekiah did not die by the sword, being allowed to live, yet the last thing he saw with his eyes were his sons being killed. The whole history of Zedekiah’s reign needs to be studied to understand why this was so. There is an excellent summary of Zedekiah in 2 Chronicles 36:10-16. It is only six short verses, but it serves as a good over-view of the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Though Zedekiah was not a good king, a king who disobedient to God, but his disobedience was likely induced by his coward nature, afraid of his priests and the strong officials and dared not say no to whatever they asked. But there were a few things that worth to note;

- In Jeremiah 34:8-9, King Zedekiah made a covenant with all the people in Jerusalem to proclaim freedom for the slaves. Whether his intention was to release labor for war, or to fulfilled the law of freeing servants to please the Lord for help, it was still a noble act.
- In Jeremiah 37:11-21, Jeremiah was imprisoned by the officials, Zedediah saved him by putting him in the courtyard of the guard and provided him food.
- In Jeremiah 38:1-13, the officials tried to kill Jeremiah, and put him into a muddy cistern. Zedekiah once again saved him and put him in the courtyard of the guard.
- In Jeremiah 38:14-28, Zedekiah promised Jeremiah would not be killed by telling him the true word from the Lord,

> 16 But King Zedekiah **swore this oath** secretly to Jeremiah: “**As surely as the Lord lives, who has given us breath, I will neither kill you nor hand you over to those who want to kill you.**” (Jeremiah 38:16 NIV)

From what he did in above, it might be the reasons God promised him a peaceful death, though punishment was necessary, that he lost his sight.

**What might cause King Josiah died by the sword?** Perhaps it was his dis-obedience to God's command spoken thru king Necho of Egypt.

> 22 Josiah, however, would not turn away from him (king Necho of Egypt), but disguised himself to engage him in battle. **He would not listen to what Necho had said at God’s command** but went to fight him on the plain of Megiddo. (2 Chronicles 35:22 NIV)

Though King Josiah was a good king, but the flourish of the kingdom made him proud. King Necho went up to fight at Carchemish was not a war of Judah. Josiah might be allied with Babylon to fight Egypt, which he should not, for the Lord was his only ally.